# How can I append geometrical objects over a circle LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, geometry

I want to draw geometric shapes over circle with using the graphics library in LibGDX like that;

[image]

As you see from image, I want to append blue shapes to black circle. Any advice ?

Comment: Are you asking about the mathematics or are you asking about using the graphics library in LibGDX? Be more specific, and you're more likely to get answers quickly.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer using the graphics library in LibGDX